# Compare between DateTime and Timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I created followed sql query and returned unpredicted results which bothers me long time.

```
SELECT 
(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 90 DAY) AS 'threshold_time', 
txs.created_at, 
(CASE WHEN txs.created_at >= 'threshold_time' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'chosen'
FROM transactions txs
```

Then result is:

```
threshold_time     |created_at         |chosen|
-------------------|-------------------|------|
2019-08-15 23:33:40|2019-10-23 05:36:22|     0|
2019-08-15 23:33:40|2019-10-24 06:02:43|     0|
2019-08-15 23:33:40|2019-11-11 01:43:36|     0|
```

which is weird that the all chosen should be 1 but it's all 0.
If I change to

```
SELECT 
(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 90 DAY) AS 'threshold_time', 
txs.created_at, 
(CASE WHEN (txs.created_at - 'threshold_time') >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'chosen'
FROM transactions txs
```

Then result is:

```
threshold_time     |created_at         |chosen|
-------------------|-------------------|------|
2019-08-15 23:51:43|2019-10-23 05:36:22|     1|
2019-08-15 23:51:43|2019-10-24 06:02:43|     1|
2019-08-15 23:51:43|2019-11-11 01:43:36|     1|
```

Could anybody explain a little bit about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `CASE` expression is comparing the `created_at` column to the *string* `'threshold_time'`:

```
CASE WHEN txs.created_at >= 'threshold_time' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Here is a corrected working version:

```
SELECT 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 90 DAY AS threshold_time, 
    txs.created_at, 
    (CASE WHEN txs.created_at >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 90 DAY
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS chosen
FROM transactions txs;
```

But actually in MySQL boolean expressions evaluate to 0 or 1 by default, so the above can be simplified to:

```
SELECT 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 90 DAY AS threshold_time, 
    txs.created_at, 
    txs.created_at >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 90 DAY AS chosen
FROM transactions txs;
```

Comment: So the second case is comparing timestamp and string but why the result is bigger than 0?

Comment: It has to do with some implicit casting which is happening.  A string _can't_ be directly compared against a date, so MySQL is casting one to the other.  What is important here is that you understand your syntax error.